# Is virtualbox a virus?

Tags: virtualbox, virus

I know a lot of people have asked this before, but I just wanted to clarify, because when I was in my virtual desktop, and I went on a site and my antivirus on my **host machine** went off saying that they blocked a threat. This scares me, because I want to use a virtual desktop to make youtube videos showcasing viruses. Is it just a false alarm? Is there a way to make the viruses not transfer to my actual computer?

My OS on the virtualmachine is windows XP 64bit and on my host machine its windows 10 64bit. My antivirus is avast. The infection says: URL:MAL 185.38.187.84/Chmj.htm

Comment: What was the threat, can you give us more information in regards to the warning, what site it was , what antivirus are you using etc.

Comment: Don't write such low quality posts with crazy questions. At least to make things better you  should add a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Your antivirus blocks any network traffic which is malicous on your PC. Kaspersky detected ECAIR antivirus test file inside a VirtualBox Windows 10 VM and blocked it when I went to the ECAIR website

Comment: So it's a false alarm?

Comment: No it is a virus which could infect your host.So I recommend that you use VirtualBox in Linux or Linux Live USB / CD

Comment: What? You telling me VirtualBox is this unsafe? Damn!

Comment: Is there any way I could possibly make the virtual machine not able to communicate with my host, so it can't infect my host?

Comment: Install Ubuntu(which doesn't need antivirus and doesn't get viruses) and install VirtualBox there

Comment: The EICAR antivirus test file is not a virus. It's an intentional false positive to confirm that antivirus is working.

Comment: Yes I know that

Comment: Of course Ubuntu can get viruses - who told you otherwise?

Comment: Ubuntu viruses are quite rare

Comment: @Cestarian It is not a virus.The guest has a virus

Comment: @SuiciDoga yeah but what I meant was, it shouldn't be that easy for viruses to infect the host from the guest...